# Combine a data frame and a list

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame of date which I want to merge with a list that has different number of rows ( 3 or 4 ).  I want to merge the first date of the data frame with all elements (dates) of the list.  For example the first two dates in df1 are merged with the first two elements of the list (bc) and I would get the following:

```
date        date1       id
1992-09-26  1992-09-05  1
1992-09-26  1992-09-12  1
1992-09-26  1992-09-19  1
1992-09-27  1992-09-06  2
1992-09-27  1992-09-13  2
1992-09-27  1992-09-20  2
```

How can I do that? I have searched this forum and did not find similar problem or comparable solution.

```
df1 <- structure(c(8304, 8305, 8306, 8307, 8308, 8309, 8310, 8311, 8312, 
8313, 8314), class = "Date")

mylist <- list(structure(c(8283, 8290, 8297), class = "Date"), structure(c(8284, 
8291, 8298), class = "Date"), structure(c(8285, 8292, 8299), class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(8279, 8286, 8293, 8300), class = "Date"), structure(c(8280, 
    8287, 8294, 8301), class = "Date"), structure(c(8316, 8323, 
    8330, 8337), class = "Date"), structure(c(8317, 8324, 8331, 
    8338), class = "Date"), structure(c(8318, 8325, 8332, 8339
    ), class = "Date"), structure(c(8319, 8326, 8333), class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(8320, 8327, 8334), class = "Date"), structure(c(8321, 
    8328, 8335), class = "Date"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for `rep` and `unlist`, as in the following:

```
A <- sapply(mylist, length)
out <- data.frame(date = rep(df1, A),
                  date1 = unlist(mylist),
                  id = rep(seq_along(A), A))
head(out)
#         date date1 id
# 1 1992-09-26  8283  1
# 2 1992-09-26  8290  1
# 3 1992-09-26  8297  1
# 4 1992-09-27  8284  2
# 5 1992-09-27  8291  2
# 6 1992-09-27  8298  2
tail(out)
#          date date1 id
# 33 1992-10-05  8320 10
# 34 1992-10-05  8327 10
# 35 1992-10-05  8334 10
# 36 1992-10-06  8321 11
# 37 1992-10-06  8328 11
# 38 1992-10-06  8335 11
```

You could also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(date = df1, date1 = mylist, key = "date")
DT[, id := 1:nrow(DT)]
DT[, as.IDate(unlist(date1), origin = "1970-01-01"), by = list(date, id)]
```

Comment: Another data.table way: `dt1 <- data.table(df1); dt1[,list(date=df1,date1=mylist[[.GRP]]),by=list(id=1:nrow(dt1))]` though the columns are out of order...

Answer (score 1):

Highly inelegant, but it works:

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", mapply(function(x,y) cbind(date=x, date1=y, id=which(df1==x)), df1, mylist)))

class(df[,1]) <- "Date"
class(df[,2]) <- "Date"

head(df)
        date      date1 id
1 1992-09-26 1992-09-05  1
2 1992-09-26 1992-09-12  1
3 1992-09-26 1992-09-19  1
4 1992-09-27 1992-09-06  2
5 1992-09-27 1992-09-13  2
6 1992-09-27 1992-09-20  2
```